# How does wordpress link columns from different tables without using FOREIGN KEY or JOIN?

Tags: wpdb, sql

I can't figure how Wordpress tables has been linked by not using `FOREIGN KEY`?
I tried to understand from [this information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13674109/mysql-whats-the-difference-between-index-unique-foreign-key-and-primary-key).

For a custom plugin I want to recreate the `terms, taxonomy and relationship tables` from wordpress in my own tables
But Wordpress do not use `FOREIGN KEY`, only 'UNIQUE KEY' and 'KEY' in sql syntaxe.

So `term_id` of `wp_term_taxonomy` isn't linked to `term_id` of `wp_terms` as one  might expect to `FOREIGN KEY (term_id) REFERENCES ". wp_terms ."(term_id)`.

Does `KEY` and `UNIQUE KEY` refer to global column name in any tables ? Does this mean that I shouldn't reuse the same table names as these of wordpress in the tables of my plugin?
my tables looks like this :

```
$wpdb->prefix . 'organization_terms';
$wpdb->prefix . 'organization_taxonomy';
$wpdb->prefix . 'organization_relationship';
```

and I would reuse the same column names as Wordpress for my tables.

the wordpress wp_terms and wp_taxonomy tables:

```
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->terms (
     term_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
     name varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
     slug varchar(200) NOT NULL default '',
     term_group bigint(10) NOT NULL default 0,
     PRIMARY KEY  (term_id),
     KEY slug (slug($max_index_length)),
     KEY name (name($max_index_length))
 ) $charset_collate;
 CREATE TABLE $wpdb->term_taxonomy (
     term_taxonomy_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
     term_id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
     taxonomy varchar(32) NOT NULL default '',
     description longtext NOT NULL,
     parent bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL default 0,
     count bigint(20) NOT NULL default 0,
     PRIMARY KEY  (term_taxonomy_id),
     UNIQUE KEY term_id_taxonomy (term_id,taxonomy),
     KEY taxonomy (taxonomy)
 ) $charset_collate;
```

More détails :
The tables in this plugin will store public, private and commercial information, and for better organization, I want to separate the management of organizations from that of the articles associated with them, which also have several article categories and will be linked to those of the organizations.

I prefer to use tables dedicated to this information rather than using the wordpress postmeta because I'm going to manage more than twenty different pieces of information for each organization and more than fifty for the membership and sales follow-up part.

Among other things, I'm using a custom postmeta table to separate and store private information (first and last names, e-mail address and telephone number).

I also want to make sure that if I need to migrate or transfer database tables for a mobile application, I can easily retrieve data by information sector.

Comment: note that custom tables is not how this is done in WordPress, and your custom tables will dramatically increase the amount of work needed, as well as create large compatibility problems. Custom post types, custom taxonomies, and post meta are how this is supposed to be done, and are more than capable of handling 50 or more attached pieces of data. If you need to look at how SQL queries are constructed in WP development then something has gone terribly wrong. Trying to create alternative tables like this is a major mistake and will create lots of problems for you, even without foreign key

Answer (score 3):

**It doesn't.** WordPress doesn't use foreign keys to link tables together that way. There are also lots and lots of other reasons to declare keys and primary keys in a table that have nothing to do with this type of linkage/referencing. For example telling MySQL/MariaDB the ID column is a primary key give critical clues and hints to how it should store and index that table for performance.

> For a custom plugin I want to recreate the terms, taxonomy and relationship tables from wordpress in my own tables But Wordpress do not use FOREIGN KEY, only 'UNIQUE KEY' and 'KEY' in sql syntaxe.

I do not see why `FOREIGN KEY` is needed for this, or why you need to create new tables.

Any "object" can have a taxonomy, not just posts. User taxonomies are a thing for example. The requirement though is that *all* objects in a taxonomy are the same type, so you can't mix users and posts as it has no way of knowing if the ID 5 is for the user 5 or the post 5.

So register a taxonomy then pass it the IDs of your custom things, not post IDs. Don't create your own tables, this will add an enormous amount of technical debt and additional work, while preventing compatibility with most of the tools available.

### How Does WP query for posts terms meta etc together?

Using SQL queries and JOIN statements constructed in PHP.

A post meta table entry has a column containing the ID of the post. When WordPress wants to fetch all meta for a post it fetches those rows that have the matching ID using a `SELECT` statement in a follow up query, or a `JOIN`. `WP_Query`, `WP_Term_Query`, `WP_User_Query` etc are the relevant classes.

Keep in mind that WordPress does not use or implement an ORM database system, and predates many of the big PHP ORM database libraries such as Doctrine. Objects such as `WP_Post` are just containers for data and can't be used to delete/update/create.

You also shouldn't be constructing your own database tables in WordPress routinely. Custom database tables are possible but there is almost no UI support for them, and no API support for accessing them beyond raw SQL.

For example when querying it might use `JOIN` to select only the post meta with an ID that matches the post, but this is all done in PHP in the application layer. **The database is unaware that the post ID 5 in the post meta tables post ID column refers to the ID of a row in the posts table.**

Note that the columns that store these IDs are just that, columns that store a number that represents an ID. There is no magic to tie it to a row in another table automatically, no links. You can create rows in the post meta table for posts that don't exist for example, nothing on the database side enforces that it must have the ID of a post that exists.

This also means if you delete a post with raw SQL it won't delete the term associations or post meta, those are all done in PHP triggering separate DB queries.

Comment: Thanks to prevent me, but I need to use these specific tables .
What I need to know is how Mysql/sql do to associate the Id of one table with the Id of other table without to know which table containing the associated Id. The index constraint is mentioned, but the name of the reference table is not.

Comment: I update my initial question to explain what I need these custom tables.

Comment: You just need to join the tables on the columns that contain the IDs.

Comment: @JacobPeattie, are you talking about [Join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)? If so, that's not what I'm trying to understand. In the "wpdb_default_tables.sql" link in my original question, Wordpress uses neither `Join` nor `Foreign Key`. How does the `DBMS` understand that the column  `term_id` of `wp_term_taxonomy` table is associated with that of `wp_terms`?

Comment: Tom already told you: _It doesn’t_.

Comment: WordPress does use joins: search the code for INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN. Foreign key constraints just enforce referential integrity - maybe in an ideal world you'd have them, but you can survive without. And IIRC early MySQL didn't support them anyway, back when it only had the myisam storage engine before it got innodb.

Comment: I understand, but that doesn't answer my original question. I've added the two WP tables concerned. How can you link the columns of two tables without `foreign key` and `Join`? Please explain, I need to understand? Thank you. I've looked into cardinalities and the database cache, but it doesn't explain how a `single key` from one table can be linked to the `primary key` of another table without naming the linked table.

Comment: @Rup, OK. Which files should I look at ? I look in wp-admin/includes/schema.php. There is no `INNER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` or `JOIN` !

Comment: I meant `UNIQUE KEY` and not `SINGLE KEY`

Comment: the 2 columns are _not_ linked at the database level. All relationships are application level in PHP. MySQL does not understand that the post ID in the post meta table is the value of an ID in the posts table, it is all done by convention and PHP logic, not database schema. `schema.php` is not responsible for the retrieval of data from the database. I'm pretty sure that your effort to create these additional tables is both unnecessary and a massive mistake, this is not how plugins are built in WordPress

Comment: you also will not find a nice and neatly contained database ORM system like you would in other systems, and unlike something like Laravel you're not meant to create new tables to achieve your goals. Needing to ask these kinds of questions is usually a strong indicator that you've misunderstood something or have headed down a dead end path

Comment: Just as examples there are joins in [wp-includes/class-wp-query.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2629) and [wp-includes/class-wp-term.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/class-wp-term.php#L132) amongst others - anywhere where WordPress assembles more complicated SELECT statements.

Comment: Thanks. About my organizations management: considering your Warning and after having analysed the database system of Woocomerce plugin I am going to put in relation a unique category table with the tables of wordpress `terms, taxonomy and relationship`. Thank you all for your help.